# What is php PECL oauth module?

Tags: php, iphone

I have to use "php PECL oauth module" in my code but I dont know anything about it. Like what is it andwhat are its uses. Please guide me and tell me about it and how to use it in my iPhone project. My question could be wrong but I think u will understand what I want to know. Answer with some code snippet will be appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Try [pecl.php.net/oauth](http://pecl.php.net/oauth) and [php.net/oauth](http://php.net/oauth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth is a is a token based iauthorization system. Once you have your security token you can identify yourself on different websites without handing out your credentials. OAuth is used by many webservice providers including Google.

You should read this:

- Google API:
  http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html
- OAuth Documentation: http://oauth.net/documentation/
- Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

If this does not help you feel free to ask a specific question on anything you can not handle.